# Why I still need dll when using /MT in an OpenCV project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll

Hi I'm trying to use /MT(Multi-threaded) in an OpenCV project in VS2015, and when I deleted the 'opencv_world400.dll', the program came with an error, indicating lack of this dll. However I think /MT means static linking so no dll is needed, what could be the problem or reason?

Comment: You will need to static library version of `opencv_world400.lib`. I suspect you are still lining with the dynamic stub library.  `/MT` only control linking of the C Runtime Support Library.  You will need different builds for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: the executable size when using /MT is about 450KB and using Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) it's about 150KB, so there's some difference

Comment: @sybob That difference is the C and C++ runtimes not opencv

Comment: @sybob the size difference is coming from the fact that your project gets the C/C++ runtimes linked in statically. No connection to OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's my misunderstanding, I'll try to build static libs of opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/MT` and `/MD` parameters specify how your project links to the C++ run-time libraries, not OpenCV. The only thing this setting has with external libraries, is that to escape conflicts all static libraries used should have the same value for this parameter, as your project.

Since you are using a dynamic build of OpenCV changing this setting does not impact OpenCV. If you would switch to a static build of OpenCV, then this parameter should match in OpenCV and your project.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable, I'll try to build my static opencv lib.

Comment: Since judging from the comments you are worried about the size, using a static OpenCV will give you smaller size since then the linker can actually include those OpenCV functions which you use instead of making a dll with all of them.

Comment: Thanks actually I want my executable run on a PC without opencv or visual studio, so I'm trying static methods.